# Want to integrate Twilio with AWS Cognito

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

We are using cognito for login and MFA for 2 factor authentication. We want to use twilio to call user on landline for OTP. Is it possible to integrate twilio and cognito ? and use twilio to send MFA OTP.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to integrate Twilio with Amazon Cognito for Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) OTP delivery. You can find more information and detailed instructions on how to set up this integration in the official AWS documentation for Cognito Custom MFA: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-mfa-custom-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to cognito, can you please help me to locate Cognito custom MFA details.